# Prove that if $x^{2}=y^{2}=0_{R}$ and $x+y$ is idempotent, then $x+y=0_{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $x,y\in R$ such that $x^{2}=y^{2}=0_{R}$. Show that if $x+y$ is idempotent, then $x+y=0_{R}$. My approach has been thus far: If $x=y=0_{R}$, then the conclusion evidently holds. If $x$ or $y$ but not both equal $0_{R}$, then we have:
$$
(x+y)^{2}=x^{2}+x.y+y.x+y^{2}=0_{R}=x+y
$$
And the desired result is reached. Let $x,y\neq0_{R}$. This is where I cannot conclude the desired result. I tried reductio ad absurdum, and added $x+y\neq0_{R}$ to the assumptions, but I failed to deduce the consequent. Could you drop a hint?

Comment: There is a problem in your proof thus far. If exactly one of $x, y$ is equal to $0_R$ (suppose $x\neq 0_R$ WLOG), then $x+y=x+0_R=x\neq 0_R$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You can get that from idempotency: $xy + yx = x + y$. Doing multiplications by $x$ and $y$ where appropriate and using $x^2 = y^2 = 0$ gives you $xy=yx=0$. Hence, the claim. I just gave out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a more detailed hint is necessary. You need to use $(x+y)^2=x+y$ in the beginning, not state it in the end. So we have
$$
x+y=(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2=xy+yx.
$$
Multiplying this equation from the left and right by $x$ respectively $y$ gives four new equations, using $x^2=y^2=0$, namely
\begin{align}
xy & = xyx\\
yx & = yxy\\
yx & = xyx\\
xy & = yxy.
\end{align}
Hence $xy=yx$ and $xyx=yxy$, so that $xy=yx=0$.

Comment: From $xy = xyx$, you can also right and left multiply to get $yxy=0$, which implies $xy=yx=0$. You could also just realize that $xy = xyx$ implies $x = 0$ and get the same conclusion. Less computation in my opinion.

Comment: @salfaris Yes, afterwards one can usually shorten it. I wanted to be systematically, like someone who tries it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you have not used the fact that $x+y$ is idempotent.

Comment: What do you mean? I used it to show that if either one of $x$ or $y$ is $0_{R}$, the result holds.

Comment: see my comments in your question